# Model conflict accurs as it says the ViewDataDictionary is passed a model @model1 but requires the model of type @model2 asp.net Identity

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

There is a conflict occurring regarding the DataViewDictionary which requires a model of different type while a different type model is being passed.

I tried to avoid this conflict by using ViewBags to get data from controllers but as a matter of fact the trick didn't work while passing data back to the controller using HttpPost requests. I have also tried using Common Model approach to resolve the issue but to no avail

```
        [AllowAnonymous]
        public IActionResult Login(string returnUrl)
        {
            Login login = new Login();
            login.ReturnUrl = returnUrl;

            return View(login);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Login(Login login )
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                ApplicationUser appUser = await userManager.FindByEmailAsync(login.Email);

                if (appUser != null)
                {
                    await signInManager.SignOutAsync();
                    Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.SignInResult result = await signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(appUser, login.Password, false, false);

                    if (result.Succeeded)
                {
                    if(User.IsInRole("Administrator") || User.IsInRole("Editor"))
                    {
                        return RedirectToAction("Dashboard", "Admin");
                    }

                    else
                    {
                        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
                    }
                }

                }

                ModelState.AddModelError(nameof(login.Email), "Login Failed: Invalid Email or password");
            }

            return View(login);
        }
```

Startup.cs code is as follows:

```
   services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>()
           .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
           .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
        services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
        {
            options.AccessDeniedPath = "/Account/AccessDenied";
            options.Cookie.Name = "Cookie";
            options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
            options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(720);
            options.LoginPath = "/Home/";
            options.ReturnUrlParameter = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.ReturnUrlParameter;
            options.SlidingExpiration = true;
        });
```

The expected result should be to login the user successfully and same for register user. But the following exception is thrown as I click the login button.

```
  InvalidOperationException: The model item passed into the ViewDataDictionary is of type 'PixageStudioWeb.Models.Login', but this ViewDataDictionary instance requires a model item of type 'PixageStudioWeb.Models.Register'.
```

I have several partial views of which some are _LoginPartial and _RegisterPartial in the Index file.I have used common model named Multimodel of which the code is as follows.

```
     @model MultiModel

     <div id="form" style="min-width:375px;">
     <div class="text-danger" asp-validation-summary="All"></div>
     <form asp-action="Login" asp-controller="Account" method="post" 
      style="margin:5px 5px 5px 5px">
      <input type="hidden" asp-for="login.ReturnUrl" />
     <ul>
       <li>
           <label asp-for="login.Email"></label>
           <input asp-for="login.Email" class="col-md-6" />
       </li> 


    <li>
        <label asp-for="login.Password"></label>
        <input type="password" asp-for="login.Password" class="col-md-6" />
    </li>
    <li>
        <button type="submit">Login</button>
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" name="remember"> 
      Remember me
        </label>
    </li>
    <li>
        <button type="button" 
      onclick="document.getElementById('id01').style.display='none'" 
      class="cancelbtn">Cancel</button>
        <span class="psw">Forgot <a href="#">password?</a></span>
    </li>
       </ul>
    </form>

     </div>
```

The Multimodel class

```
      public partial class MultiModel
     {
    public IEnumerable<Category> categories { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<ImagePool> images { get; set; }
    public Login login { get; set; }
    public Register register { get; set; }
     }
```

Comment: Can we see your view?

Comment: @bolkay please review the changes I have added one of the views and the common model

Comment: Check the model directive on the login page. It's likely not to be the `Login` model. I recommend you use different ViewModels for Login and Registration.